# How to combine multiple ranges with getRange in order to clear the contents of specific cells?

Tags: google-apps-script

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VsEvt2KnYGnlN_qHjkjPohVHF5MUqfyHD7tSk0VpkqA/edit#gid=1418057437

I use this sheet to enter data of patients in (Data_Entry) tab. Specific rows are titles and should not be cleared whenever I clear contents of all cells in the sheet/tab. Like Rows 1-4 and rows 20-21. So I made this script to clear specific cells but it seems very basic and it has a problem whenever somebody inserts a new row in between, the whole range needs to be adjusted.

*The script has three functions: adding_menu, making borders of query results in (All_patients)tab and **ClearContents of (Data_Entry) tab**.*

**So my question is about the last function (ClearContent)**

```
 function onOpen() {

    var menuItems = [
    {name: 'ClearContents', functionName: 'ClearContents'},
    {name: 'Borders', functionName: 'borders'}
  ];
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Weekened_Functions', menuItems);
 
 
}

function borders() {
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('All_Patients').getDataRange();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('All_Patients').getRange("B50:H200")
  cell.setBorder(false, false, false, false, false, false);
  var values = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 2; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 1; j < values[i].length; j++) {
      
        range.getCell(i + 1, j + 1).setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);
      }
    }
 
  }
 
function ClearContents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data_Entry');
  sheet.getRange('B5:F19').clearContent(),
  sheet.getRange('B22:F34').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B37:F49').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B52:F64').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B67:F83').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B86:F102').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B105:F119').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B122:F133').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B136:F146').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B149:F160').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B163:F174').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B177:F188').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B191:F202').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B205:F216').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B219:F230').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B247:F257').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B260:F269').clearContent();

  sheet.getRange('M5:M19').clearContent(),
  sheet.getRange('M22:M34').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M37:M49').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M52:M64').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M67:M83').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M86:M102').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M105:M119').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M122:M133').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M136:M146').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M149:M160').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M163:M174').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M177:M188').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M191:M202').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M205:M216').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M219:M230').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M247:M257').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('M260:M269').clearContent();

  sheet.getRange('H5:H19').clearContent(),
  sheet.getRange('H22:H34').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H37:H49').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H52:H64').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H67:H83').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H86:H102').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H105:H119').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H122:H133').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H136:H146').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H149:H160').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H163:H174').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H177:H188').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H191:H202').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H205:H216').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H219:H230').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H247:H257').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('H260:H269').clearContent();
};
```

1\ how to combine these ranges in simple formula?

2\ Is there a way to add exception like: (clear contents of all cells except Column M and Column A and cells containing text "Ward" or "room"or problem list" or "recommendations"?

Comment: Can you clean up your code here and in the answer to shorten the list of cells to just 3? There's no point in listing more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved
by using [`getRangeList()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations) , assign any range list to a variable then use these variables anywhere

```
var ranges = sheet.getRangeList(['B5:I21' ,'B24:I36' , 'B39:I53' , 'B56:I68',  'B71:I90' , 'B93:I109' , 'B112:I126' , 'B129:I140' , 'B143:I157' , 'B160:I174'  ,'B177:I188' , 'B191:I204' , 'B207:I220' , 'B223:I234' , 'B237:I248','B251:I262','B265:I275','B278:I287','B5:I21']);

ranges.clearcontent();
```