# How to combine ranges of getRange in one variable in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am clearing the content of specific ranges of cell through this code:

```
function ClearContents() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Data_Entry');
      
  sheet.getRange('B5:I21').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B24:I36').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B39:I53').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B56:I68').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B71:I90').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B93:I109').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B112:I126').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B129:I140').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B143:I157').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B160:I174').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B177:I188').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B191:I204').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B207:I220').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B223:I234').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('B237:I248').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B251:I262').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B265:I275').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B278:I287').clearContent();
sheet.getRange('B5:I21').clearContent();
 
};
```

And I would like to make it cleaner code by using a variable that contains all of these ranges with this code:

```
var ranges = sheet.getRange[sheet.getRange('B5:I21'),  sheet.getRange('B24:I36'),  sheet.getRange('B39:I53'),  sheet.getRange('B56:I68'),  sheet.getRange('B71:I90'),  
sheet.getRange('B93:I109'),  sheet.getRange('B112:I126'),  sheet.getRange('B129:I140'),  
sheet.getRange('B143:I157'),  sheet.getRange('B160:I174'),  sheet.getRange('B177:I188'),  
sheet.getRange('B191:I204'),  sheet.getRange('B207:I220'),  sheet.getRange('B223:I234'),  
sheet.getRange('B237:I248'),sheet.getRange('B251:I262'),sheet.getRange('B265:I275'),
sheet.getRange('B278:I287'),sheet.getRange('B5:I21')];
  
  ranges.clearContent();
```

But it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Didn't you ask the very same question 2 weeks earlier? [How to combine multiple ranges with getRange in order to clear the contents of specific cells?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/151412/how-to-combine-multiple-ranges-with-getrange-in-order-to-clear-the-contents-of-s)

Also, no need for a ton of cells in the example. Three would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

solved

`var ranges=sheet.getRangeList(['B5:I21' ,'B24:I36' , 'B39:I53' , 'B56:I68',  'B71:I90' , 'B93:I109' , 'B112:I126' , 'B129:I140' , 'B143:I157' , 'B160:I174'  ,'B177:I188' , 'B191:I204' , 'B207:I220' , 'B223:I234' , 'B237:I248','B251:I262','B265:I275','B278:I287','B5:I21']);`

`ranges.clearcontent();`